# save image in local machine

Tags: php

I have made an application that convert a text into image format now how do i save the converted image in my local machine,

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using GD image functions to create the image? So if you are already getting PHP to display the image, you can encourage the browser to download it instead by adding `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.fileext"');` to the top of your file. This will encourage the browser to pop up a download box. The filename attribute is the name that the browser will prompt to save the image as